# sorting data in a column table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to sort column data in my table which is generated from mysql. This is how I want my table to be:-

```
<th><a href='view.php?sort=first_name'>First Name</th>
<th><a href='view.php?sort=last_name'>Last Name</th>
```

this is my query but I'm getting an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users")
    if($_GET['sort'] == 'first_name'){
     $result .= "ORDER BY first_name";
    }
   else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'last_name'){
     $result .= "ORDER BY last_name";
    }
    or die(mysql_error());
```

I know my problem is in the query, but how can I correct it?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: A decent IDE and some basic debugging ability would make the errors in your code quite obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is a space required infront of the ORDER BY keyword and there are some improper terminations. Try now.**

```
 $result = "SELECT * FROM users";
    if($_GET['sort'] == 'first_name'){
     $result .= " ORDER BY first_name";
    }
   else if($_GET['sort'] == 'last_name'){
     $result .= " ORDER BY last_name";
    }
$result = mysql_query($result) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your answer is missing the semicolon at the end of the mysql_query() statement. Granted, it shouldn't be ran at that point, but that's another issue. Edit: Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You miss a semicolon and a space here:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users ");
                                          ^  ^
```

The `Parse error` is due to the missing semicolon, the other error will come later :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to have extra space between the column name and `ORDER BY` clause.

```
$result .= " ORDER BY first_name";
            ^ add extra space here
```

also

```
$result .= " ORDER BY last_name";
            ^ add extra space here
```

full snippet:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";
if($_GET['sort'] == 'first_name')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY first_name";
}
else if ($_GET['sort'] == 'last_name')
{
    $query .= " ORDER BY last_name";
}
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

or why not directly do this,

```
$sortColumn = $_GET['sort'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $sortColumn";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: While this surely fixes one of OP's problems, it does not fix the error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in C`.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY $sortColumn";` is a terrible idea. You need to validate and sanitize the data before hand.